# Example when two strings compared by == and equals() will give different results?

Tags: java, string, string-literals

When is `a == b` is true but `a.equals(b)` is false, or vice versa?

I know that `equals()` is used to compare the values of the Strings and the `=`= to check if two variables point at the same instance of a String object.
But in which case will these two be different ?

Comment: "when a==b is true but a.equals(b) is false" no, properly implemented `equals` method always returns true for `x.equals(x)`, "or vice versa" read two same strings from file and compare them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this code,

```
String str1 = "ABC";
String str2 = new String("ABC");
System.out.println(str1==str2); // false
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2)); //true
```

The reason for this is that when you write `String str1="ABC"` this string is kept in **string pool** and `String str2 = new String("ABC")` creates the new object in **heap** and it won't check the string pool if it is already present. But as contents of the both string are same, **equals** method returns true.

Comment: You might add that if a==b, then a.equals(b) should always return true since they are actually the same object.

Comment: Maybe you should also explain the why of the results, IMO.

Comment: @nbro Edited and tried to explain.

Comment: @MandeepRajpal, thats not the reason, please correct it. If you create both strings in the heap then also it will give the same result as above.

Answer (score 2):

While most compilers will intern strings so that

```
a = "Foo";
b = "Foo";
System.out.println(a == b);
```

will generally print `True`, you can always construct strings that you know to be identical but the compiler does not:

```
a = "Foo";
b = "Fo";
c = "o";
System.out.println((a == b + c));
```

This will just about always print `False`, while `a.equals(b + c)` will always be `True`. Basically, there is no guarantee that strings with the same content will point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in nature. So, when we do this,

```
String a1 = "a";
String a2 = "a";
```

Actually in memory, only one instance of String "a" is created. Both a1 and a2 will point to the same instance.

That's why, `a1 == a2` and `a1.equals(a2)` are both true.

But, in this,

```
String a1 = "a";
String a2 = new String("a");
```

We created a new String instance explicitly. So, `a1.equals(a2)` will be true. But `a1 == a2` will not.